# Fesh Eclipse unzipped does not run in mac OS?

Tags: eclipse

My new Eclipse does not run at all, it gives the following message.

[image]

Hope some one have a solution for this, thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Eclipse? It looks from the crash image as though it might be 3.8 - which is very old. Eclipse 4.6.2 is the current Eclipse.

Comment: it is eclipse Juno which is a requirement for the old project I'll work with

Comment: If this is a plug-in or RCP you are working on you can still use the current Eclipse and use a Target Platform containing the old Eclipse.

Comment: I want to set the environment for the first time so i have not an old eclipse, but I have tried many versions and